# How to convert php SQL statement to GORM Golang query?

Tags: mysql, sql, go, go-gorm

I have a SQL command in PHP as follows:

`UPDATE tbl1 AS A,tbl2 AS B SET A.field1 = '1' WHERE A.field2=B.field2 AND B.field3 = {$var};`

I need to write the command in golang using gorm package and this is what I am trying:

`db.Table("tbl1 as A").Joins("INNER JOIN tbl2 B on A.field2 = B.field2").Where("B.field3 = ?", var).Update("A.field1", "1")`

But in the terminal, this query is being interpreted as :

`` UPDATE tbl1 as A SET `A`.`field1`='1' WHERE tbl2.person_id = var ``

How do I frame the gorm query properly? I dont want to use db.Exec() or db.Raw() and I dont have the structure for the two tables. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why bother? If you know the SQL, just use it. Gorm lets you execute raw SQL.  When an abstraction ceases to be useful, stop using it.